# C# LINQ Query 

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query:

```
var results = from theData in GeometricAverage
              group theData by new { study = theData.study, groupNumber = theData.groupNumber, GeoAverage= theData.GeoAverage } into grp
              select new
              {
                  study = grp.Key.study,
                  groupNumber = grp.Key.groupNumber,
                  TGI = testFunction(grp.Key.GeoAverage, Also here I want to pass in the GeoAverage for only group 1 (but for each individual study))
              };
```

What I want to do is that for each study, there are multiple groups with a GeoAverage figure for each group.  The TGI is calculated by passing the GeoAverage figure for each group and the GeoAverage figure for group 1 (on each study) into the testFunction.  I can't figure out how to pass in the value just for group 1.

Hope this makes sense.

EDIT: Sample of data:

```
Study  Group  GeoAverage
 1       1        3
 1       2        5
 1       3        6
 2       1        2
 2       2        3
 2       3        9
```

So, for the above data, I would want each GeoAverage figure for each group, to be evaluated against the GeoAverage figure of group 1 within that same study.  So if I have say a function:

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

Using the data above, I would first evaluate study 1, group 1 against itself, so pass in GeoAverage 3 twice and return 9.  For Study 1, group 2, pass in group 2 GA at 5, and that studys group1 GA at 3, returning 15.

Comment: Your data is unclear; what are you *not* grouping by? I only see you using the `Key` in the select statement.

Comment: A sample of the data and expected results would help too...

Comment: Additional Info added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have now worked it out.  I iterate through a collection of data that I want the value to be stored against and use the following two LINQ queries:

```
foreach (var data in compoundData)
        {
            var controlValue = from d in GeometricAverage
                               where d.study == data.study
                               where d.groupNumber == "1"
                               select d.GeoAverage;

            var treatmentValue = from l in GeometricAverage
                                 where l.study == data.study
                                 where l.groupNumber == data.groupNumber
                                 select l.GeoAverage;


            data.TGI = CalculateTGI(controlValue, treatmentValue);

        }
```